# At which level should I start doing the missions to get a Tauntaun?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I already understand how to get a Tauntaun. You go to a nest and try to get the older tauntauns to return. If you succeed, a wampa will appear and you have to kill it. After killing it, you get the data for the vendor.

However, which level is the wampa at? 41? 55? Even though the majority of animals on Hoth are level 40, I've run into level 55 tauntauns that decreased my health by 50 percent in a few seconds. What level are the wampas that appear and attack you? I want to know if it is a good idea to do it at level 40 or 55.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wampa will spawn at the same level you are, though higher-level players in the area could spawn others that might attack you.  Prior to 4.0 you wouldn't want to go earlier than level 35 since the other level 40+ NPCs in the area could kill you easily, but now thanks to Level Sync this is not a concern.

The level 55s on Hoth were added with Patch 2.0 as part of the Seeker Droid/Macrobinoculars questlines, and you shouldn't run into them unless you are exploring areas you don't otherwise need to visit.